# weak convergence of discrete probability measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I'm doing a problem from Billingsley  Probability and measure (problem 25.4). I don't know from where to start, any help is appreciated:

1). Show that for each probability measure $\mu$ on the line there exist probability
measures $\mu_n$ with finite support such that $\mu_n => \mu$ (weak convergence).

2). Show further that $\mu_n\{x\}$ can be taken rational and that each point in the support can be taken rational

From my readings for 1) there are hints about taking the indicator function and for 2) $\mu_n$ is discrete since $\mu_n\{x\} \neq 0$, this is  my thoughts actually.

Comment: I would work with associated distribution function, use characterization of weak convergence in terms of convergence of associated distribution function and construct distribution functions that converge to the one associated with $\mu$. When is a distribution function associated with a probability measure of finite support? When is that support in $\mathbb{Q}$ and when is the range of the measure in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so you think that I use the cdf. I'm thnking about $F_n$ the empirical distribution which converge almost surely  to $F$, But I'm thniking about 2 how to define  a discrete  measure with rational finite support...